# NoClassDefFoundError on a dependency class in a web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3, noclassdeffounderror

I have a web application A, which depends on library B, which, in turn, uses library C. A, B and C are all Maven projects (A is a `war`, B and C are `jar`s).

When I deploy A to the application container, some method of a class in B is invoked, which refers to class D in library C.

At that point, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for D. D uses (imports) packages `java.sql` and `org.slf4j`.

I explored following hypotheses and none of them was true:

1. **Different versions of C are used.** In order to exclude this hypothesis, I ran `mvn dependency:tree` in the directory of A and I found only one reference to C.
2. **C is not included in the `war` file of A.** I opened the file `target\A.war\WEB-INF\lib\C.jar\` and the class file of D was present at the correct location (i. e. this hypothesis is incorrect).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: If the Class D is in the jar C but not packaged into the war file you have a problem with the dependencies in your war project. Simply show all pom file so it's possible to help.

Comment: @khmarbaise D **is** packaged into the war file.

Comment: Please show the pom files!

Comment: And show the full stack trace of the exception, after a fresh deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that library B was obfuscated with ProGuard. After I disabled its obfuscation, everything started to work.